# How to set table cell value using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to set the value of all the cells of a table by iterating through them.
Ideally I would like to access a Html table like an array i.e. `$("#tbl")[row][col]="5"`

This does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            $("#tbl").children().children()[row].children()[col].append("sdfasdf");
        }
    }
});
```

This works but I dont know why!!!

1. I dont understand  $("#tbl").children()**.children()** why the need for the 2nd children
2. Why is the 3rd children not a function i.e. children() like the 1st 2.
3. Why is'nt innerHTML not a function i.e. innerHTML()

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       for (var row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
           for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
               $("#tbl").children().children()[row].children[col].innerHTML = "H!";
           }
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Sorry I can't format my edit code, Does'nt seem to work

Comment: See my edit for the answers to your numbered questions. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for code formatting - I'll clean up this question for you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you just want to iterate over each cell in the table, either of the following will work:

```
$('#tbl td').each(function ()
{
    var $cell = $(this);
    // do something with the current <td>
});

// or,

$('#tbl tr').each(function ()
{
    var $row = $(this);
    $row.children().each(function ()
    {
        var $cell = $(this);
        // do something with the current <tr> and <td>
    });
});
```

---

If you want to access the table like an array, you're going to have to build an array yourself:

```
var arr = $('#tbl > tbody > tr').map(function ()
{
    return $(this).children().map(function ()
    {
        return $(this);
    });
});
```

However, jQuery doesn't expose an API such that you'll (ever) be able to do simple assignment, as in `arr[row][col] = 5;`. With the above array, this will work:

```
arr[row][col].text(5);
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/3nMfV/)***

---

#### Edit

> (1) I dont understand $("#tbl").children().children() why the need for the 2nd children

Because jQuery's `.children()` function only returns a set of the element's **immediate** descendants, not all descendents (e.g. children + grandchildren + ...).

> (2) Why is the 3rd children not a function i.e. children() like the 1st 2.

Because when you use array notation to access elements of a jQuery collection, you get back the underlying DOM element, not a jQuery object. Use [`.eq(i)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) instead of `[i]`:

```
$("#tbl").children().children().eq(row).children().eq(col).append("sdfasdf");
```

> (3) Why is'nt innerHTML not a function i.e. innerHTML()

As in the answer to your question #2, `...children()[col]` returns back a DOM element, not a jQuery object. Most browsers support the DOM [`element.innerHTML` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML).

When using `.eq(i)` instead of `[i]`, as above, use the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) jQuery function.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my question. I appreciate your explanation But I prefer my answer to the initial question (For any one looking for a solution to "How to set table cell value using jquery").

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this selector `$('#myTable tr:nth-child('+row+') td:nth-child('+col'+)').html("sdfasdf");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $rows = $("#tbl").find("tr");
    for (var row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
       var $columns = $($rows[row]).find("td"); 
       for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
             $($columns[col]).append("sdfasdf");
        }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to assign a value to all the cells try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tbl td").append("sdfasdf");
});
```

If you want to extract the cells as 2 dimensional array:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rowsNcells = $.map($("#tbl tr"),
    function(el, ind){
        var row = [];
        $("td", el).each(function(){
            row.push(el);
        });
        return row;
    });
});
```

and then somewhere in the code.

```
$(rowNcells[1][2]).text("Something");
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>

var tr = 1;
$('table tr').each(function(){
    var td = 1;
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        $(this).append(' | TR : ' + tr + ' TD : ' + td );
         td++;
    });
    tr++;
});
```

**Live demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/8xFFH/**

Iterates through all the TD's so you know which you're in. You can also just use `$('table tr td').append()` if it's a static append.