# jquery set innerHTML for a cell in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

I want to print a value in each table cell after creating it dynamically.

```
<table id="MapDetails"><tr>
<td/><td/><td/><td/>
var colIndex = 4;
foreach(MapDetail geMapDetail in Model.mapDetails)
{    
<td class="test">
       <script>{getPosition(@geResult.assessmentId, @colIndex, @rowIndex, '@geResult.ResultValue');}</script>
</td>
colIndex++;
}
</tr></table>
```

**My script**

**THIS DOES NOT WORK**

```
function getPosition(id, colIndex, rowIndex, resultValue) {

    var element = '#' + id;
    var cell = $('#MapDetails tr:eq(' + rowIndex + ') td:eq(' + colIndex + ')');
     if($(element).index() == colIndex){
        cell.innerHTML = resultValue;
     }

}
```

**THIS WORKS ONLY FOR THE FIRST CELL**

```
function getPosition(id, colIndex, rowIndex, resultValue) {

    var element = '#' + id;
    var cell = $(".test").closest('tr').find('td').get(colIndex);
     if($(element).index() == colIndex){
        cell.innerHTML = resultValue;
     }

}
```

Comment: have you give different id to all cells ?

Comment: @YasinPatel `td`s don't have any classname or id in the given markup.

Comment: _creating it dynamically._.....How you are doing this?

Comment: td has a class name test in the markup i have given above <table id="MapDetails"><tr><td class="test">

Comment: this td is in a forloop i am editing code to show..this is a very stripped down version of actual code to make my question clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here: [How to set table cell value using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624704/how-to-set-table-cell-value-using-jquery)

so i did:

```
var cell = $("#MapDetails").children().children()[rowIndex].children[colIndex];
```

and that's it! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly a algorithm problem. You must loop through all TRs and nested TDs and write that one value that you want to write.

```
$('#tableid').find('tr').each(function(index, element){

  $(element).find('td').each(function(indexd, elementd){

    $(elementd).html('blah blah');

 });

});
```

Comment: what is meant by element here? in my code element is totally different from cell. also i am present inside the td itself when i call my getPosition function so traversing every time doesnt seem like a good idea...i have tried $(this).parent().children('td').get(colIndex) but even that doesnt work

Comment: please ask the question properly..I answered your question "I want to print a value in each table cell after creating it dynamically"